# Cordova Android 7 calling to unknown plugins

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When running a `cordova-android@7.1` version application various errors are received:

```
D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: Badge
D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: File
D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: Keyboard
D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: BuildInfo
D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: Device
```

and

```
W/SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist
```

appear to be the most pertinent. I assume the whitelist issue is similar to the other plugins not being accessible since it is a also a plugin. There is no `<feature>` aspect for each plugin in the `res/xml/config.xml` file which I thought was required in the past.

I do have the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` installed and `<access origin="*" />`, `allow-navigation`, and `allow-intent`, in my `config.xml` file and these do propagate to the `res/xml/config.xml` file.

All of the plugins are installed and their sources are visible inside the android directory.

I am also using ionic v1 currently however in my research I was unable to find any issues in regards to ionic v1 and cordova-android v7, but figured it was worth a mention.

Some things I've tried:

- remove and reinstall plugins
- remove cordova whitelist plugin entirely (I read something about android cordova including this nowadays)
- <strike>starting up a fresh app with android@7 with the device + buildinfo plugins and it worked fine and the plugins were accessible</strike>
- with only the two plugins it was fine but I just tried with *all* the plugins and it threw the same error so I'm currently investigating further on this path...
- beat my head against a concrete wall
- several manual changes against the platform directory
- several `cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android` commands
- reinstall cordova cli version to latest version (currently on 8)

List of plugins in project:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="^2.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="^0.9.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^3.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="^0.8.5" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-3dtouch" spec="^1.3.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-touchid" spec="^0.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.2.0" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-deploy" spec="^0.6.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="^3.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.2.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
... and some other unneeded plugins now that we have an answer.
```

I am totally able to build the application at this point which was a major hurdle to overcome for `cordova-android@7` in general, and I want to build this on 7+ so answers recommending a downgrade to 6.4 aren't needed.

> When I ran the test application with nothing but plugins in it I could access them all almost invariably but only in certain, random, cases did the build turn out that I couldn't access any plugins. The next time I built it it worked fine!
>
> As well, during the initial process of just getting the app to build I ran into several `AndroidManifest.xml` not existing errors and I fixed all of them. So, even though the plugins were incompatible and throwing an in app error, the application would still build as though everything was fine!
>
> The solution was to fork *every single plugin* and fix the target directories of the various pieces of the `plugin.xml` file. See @bshaps answer for the original indication of this and @forrestmid's answer for some additional clarification on the changes needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason people recommend downgrading to platform version 6.4.0 is because 7+ contained changes that broke most of the existing plugins at the time.  At this point many have been updated, but plugins such as `cordova-plugin-badge` are not compatible with android platform 7+ and haven't been updated recently.

Your options if you don't want to downgrade to 6.4.0:

1. Wait for the author to update the plugin to be compatible with Android Platform 7+
2. Fork the plugin on Github and make the changes to be compatible with Android 7+
3. Remove the plugins that are not up to date for Android 7+

I've heard from others that updating the plugins to be compatible with Android 7+ is pretty simple if you know what you're doing.

Comment: It is indeed a simple change. See my modified question and answer for additional clarification as to why I thought the plugins were compatible but why that was indeed the reason the app was failing at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is as @bshaps stated, that some of the plugins were *still* not compatible with cordova-android@7. The reason I didn't believe this to be the case when I asked my question was because **the incompatible plugins were still sometimes working on cordova-android@7!**

To fix all the plugins you not only have to update the `AndroidManifest.xml` location as in the [cordova blogpost](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html), but you also have to change the following strings inside of the `plugin.xml` file in each of the plugins:

- `res/xml/config.xml` to `app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml`
- `res/values/strings.xml` to `app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`
- `res/xml/strings.xml` to `app/src/main/res/xml/strings.xml`

and, of course

- `AndroidManifest.xml` to `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

It is indeed a very simple fix. What also threw me off was that the `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin required `cordova-android@7.1.0` or higher but it too wasn't configured appropriately with the strings above.

I'm giving credit to @bshaps for this because if he hadn't specifically called out `cordova-plugin-badge` as being invalid I would have thought that, since the app was building fine, the plugins must have been compatible. *This is not the case.* You can still build the app with incompatible plugins that will throw errors during runtime.

Comment: Sorry, which blog post?

Comment: @BenCoffin Just added that.

Comment: thank you, i'm getting _07-20 13:53:30.908: D/PluginManager(24001): exec() call to unknown plugin: Camera_ with cordova-plugin-camera, and am going to endeavor to follow your advice to fix that issue with cordova-android@7.1.0

Comment: These modifications allowed me to use the file transfer plugin (cordova-plugin-file-transfer) with Cordova 8.0.0.